# Splitting elements to different number of lists in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I have a problem with separating elements to different lists in Java. The problem is actually I need uncertain number of new lists. For example I have a method which returns a list contains some number of objects but if I have 50 elements in that list I want to split them to the small lists. For 50 elements I will need 10 new lists to put these elements inside but if that number will increase to 100 I will need 20 new lists. Is there any way to say Java automatically generate a new list for me if it is needed?

Comment: Create a `List<List>`

Comment: Apart from coding it yourself? What have you done so far to split the lists?

Comment: you'll have to check length of list on base of it make if condition then process list inside it as you want.

Comment: I don't see the reason why you want to split list into small ones. You can always use `subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` method of the `List` class to split original list into groups.

Comment: I'll try to explain: for exmp. in first step my main method returns me 50 customers, 10 of them live in the same city then I want to put these 10 in a list, if 5 other r also in same but different city from the fist one then put them in a new list (I'm doing all that controls inside loops and they're ok) , I mean I want to categorize my fist list according to the customer's specific feature(not city mine more complex than this case) But I can't know what those cities will be if I run method again and gives me different customer lists. Maybe there will be 100 customers and different cities...

Comment: This last comment is a useful clarification; you should edit your question so that it has this information as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want what is often called a "grouping" operation. To take your simplified example (from the comments), you have a bunch of `Customer` objects and you want to group them into separate lists categorized by `City`. (Your real problem may be more complex than this, but let's run with the `City` example for the moment.)

To have an arbitrary number of lists, a convenient way for organizing them is to create a `Map<City, List<Customer>>`. That is, you have a map whose key is `City` and whose value is a `List` of `Customer` objects that are from that `City`.

It's fairly straightforward to write an ordinary loop that runs through an input `List<Customer>` and stores them into `Map` as I've described above. A small wrinkle is that you have to handle creating the `List` and putting it into the `Map` the first time you encounter a `Customer` from a `City` that you haven't seen before. Here's the code:

```
List<Customer> inputList = ...;
Map<City, List<Customer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Customer cust : inputList) {
    City city = cust.getCity();
    List<Customer> custList = map.get(city);
    if (custList == null) {
        custList = new ArrayList<>();
        map.put(city, custList);
    }
    custList.add(cust);
}
```

In Java 8, you can use new method `Map.computeIfAbsent()` to save a bit of trouble with handling the special case of creating the list for the first customer from a city:

```
Map<City, List<Customer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Customer cust : inputList) {
    City city = cust.getCity();
    map.computeIfAbsent(city, k -> new ArrayList<>());
    map.get(city).add(cust);
}
```

But if you're using Java 8, you might as well use the Streams API, which has a `Collectors` class that can do this kind of grouping very conveniently:

```
Map<City, List<Customer>> map =
    inputList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Customer::getCity));
```